# ESL Teacher to Spanish Speakers

Tags: syntax, semantics

I think I might have once read in a sample resume someone wrote as a bullet point under their work experience that for a period of time they were an "ESL teacher to Spanish speakers" --honestly, I don't remember if it actually was *Spanish speakers*, but it certainly was speakers whose native language wasn't English.

Anyway, I would like to know if "ESL teacher to Spanish speakers" would sound natural and make sense to write it like that.

Now, TBH, I've already asked other native speakers of English and they said a native speaker would never use that structure. They suggested using something like "Taught Spanish speakers ESL" or "Taught ESL to Spanish speakers" instead.

If you can say you teach something to someone, why can't you say *you're a teacher of something to someone*, as in, for example, *"I've been an English teacher to Japanese speakers for a year now"*?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why a native speaker would say they would never use that structure.  It sounds fairly reasonable to me.  You were a teacher; what kind of teacher?  An ESL teacher.  And who were you a teacher to?  Spanish  speakers.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your prompt answer, stangdon. Apprecaite it.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly acceptable to say:

> I was an ESL teacher to Spanish speakers.

However, I might modify it slightly:

> I was an ESL teacher to Spanish-speaking students.

Comment: Or "I was an ESL teacher to native Spanish speakers", right? How does that sound for being more precise?